# HTML webresource editor changing source code after submit

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I created a new html webresource in order to use it as an iframe. I am using VS 2010 to create the website, for testing I copy the source code to the MSCRM html editor. At the beginning this worked fine, but now the site has grown and I detected that the editor adapts my source code when clicking 'Ok'.

Example:
After copying source code to MSCRM editor
[image: After copying source code to MSCRM editor]

After clicking 'OK' and reopening webresource:
[image: After clicking 'OK' and reopening webresource]

I noticed, that the editor always cuts the source code after the second `</script>`-tag. Is there any option to disable this function or any workaround?

Edit:

I also tried to change tab and then click 'OK', but the problem is that my javascript manipulates DOM and when changing the tab the editor also manipulates my source code.

Example:
After copying source code to MSCRM editor

[image: After copying source code to MSCRM editor]

After changing tab:
[image: After changing tab]

After clicking 'OK' and reopening webresource:
[image: reopened webresource]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you faced it's a common issue with the built-in web resource editor of Dynamics CRM.

My suggestions are:

- Always upload a file instead of editing the source code
- Use a tool like `Web Resource Manager` included inside [XrmToolbox](http://xrmtoolbox.codeplex.com/)
- Use the [Developer Toolkit for Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh372957.aspx) included inside the SDK

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried the Developer Toolkit and it is working well.

Comment: +1 for always uploading a file instead of editing the source code. Only the very simplest of code should be done with the editor.